# Python cgi only runs from home directory

Tags: python, apache, cgi

i'm facing a pretty crazy problem at the moment:

If I run my python cgi script in my home directory its working but if i run it in cgi-bin folder of my apache i get this error:

```
End of script output before headers: cgi_script.py
```

There is no SElinux enabled on this server.

This is my Apache conf:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/path/to/cgi-bin/"

<Directory "/path/to/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Cgi-script permissions are 775 and owned by the apache user.

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT:
Just found the error... Shebang was wrong.

Comment: "*Just found the error... Shebang was wrong.*" - and how could anyone this side of the question know that when you did not show your code?

Comment: The problem is still existing on another server with the same cgi script.